# Confusion regarding the proof steps of the topology generated by a subbasis

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation, product-space

Munkres, page 88, Theorem 15.2
[image]

[image]

The author outlines the proof (given above) that the subbasis $S$ generates the topology $\tau'$ which is same as the product topology $\tau$. The proof can be broken down into two steps. First: every element of $S$ belongs to $\tau$. So $\tau' \subset \tau$. Second step: every elements of the basis (let's call it $B$) of $\tau$ is a finite intersection of the elements of $S$. So, $\tau \subset \tau'$.

My question is why do we need two steps? Isn't it sufficient to prove that the basis $B'$ corresponding to the subbasis $S$ is the same as the basis $B$ that generates $\tau$? In that case, the two basis sets ($B$ and $B'$) are equal and hence the topology generated by the two basis sets should also be the same. Is it a good line of proof?

Comment: The first remark is just the observation that the topology generated by a subbase can be seen as the *minimal* topology that contains that subbase. And $\pi_1^{-1}[U]=U \times Y \in \mathcal{T}$ etc. so the observation $\mathcal{S} \subseteq \mathcal{T}$ holds true.

Comment: Two inclusions is often the fast way to show equality of families of sets. You will see this time and again (also in measure theory etc.). You can use minimality arguments etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathcal{S}$ is indeed a subbase for some topology $\mathcal{T}'$ on $X \times Y$. In general we can write the members of this $\mathcal{T}'$ as "arbitrary unions of (finite intersections from $\mathcal{S}$)", so as the result of a two step process:

1. Take all finite intersections from $\mathcal{S}$, so form $$\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{S}) = \{\bigcap_{i=1}^n S_i\mid n=1,2,3,4,\ldots, S_1, \ldots S_n \in \mathcal{S}\}$$

note that in particular $\mathcal{S}\subseteq \mathcal{B}$.

2. $\mathcal{T'}$ is the unique topology that has $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{S})$ as a basis, so

$$\mathcal{T'}= \{\bigcup \mathcal{B}'\mid \mathcal{B}' \subseteq \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{S})\}$$ and this is well-defined because $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{S})$ is a basis for some topology (it obeys the two conditions given by Munkres when he first discusses a basis for a topology).

In this case, $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{S})$ is just the set $\{U \times V\mid U\subseteq X \text{ open }, V \subseteq Y \text{ open }\}$, i.e. the standard basis for the product topology that Munkres gives as a definition.

So by unicity of the generated topology from a basis, $\mathcal{T}'$, generated from $\mathcal{S}$ in these steps is *exactly* the product topology.

So what you propose *is* enough, don't worry. What Munkres does is to avoid the proof that  "$\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{S})$ is just the set $\{U \times V\mid U\subseteq X \text{ open }, V \subseteq Y \text{ open }\}$", which **is** true but a bit tedious notationwise, and replace it by a slightly more abstract argument involving both $\mathcal{T}'$ and the product topology $\mathcal{T}$.

I hope this helps.